# How to use non-bocking session store?

Tags: php, mysql

I know session file store will blocking the http request.

I know could use the session_write_close() method to unlock the file blocking,

But I want to know If I use mysql store for my session it is still blocking the http request?

If I use mysql store for my session would I still need to use session_write_close() method to unlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to know If I use mysql store for my session it is still blocking the http request?

No, records mysql can't be locking between different connections in standard way.

Comment: So if I use mysql store way that is non-blocking session?

Comment: Yes. To make a blocking session with MySQL will need to do extra work.

Comment: @joe, but remember that you can lose some data with this way.

Comment: Is that true? But a lot of people are using the mysql store have not this problem ?

Comment: @joe, it's true. Loading in chronological order: start page one, start page two, save on page two value 2 in session, save  on page one value 1 in session. Value 2, was lost.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this problem ? But is non-blocking way!?

Comment: May be. But it seems complicated(may be for another question). But do not be afraid it... if pages loading very fast you will avoid this.